# crash when using stl vector at instead of operator[]

Tags: c++, stl, vector, crash

I have a method as follows (from a class than implements TBB task interface - not currently multithreading though)
My problem is that two ways of accessing a vector are causing quite different behaviour - one works and the other causes the entire program to bomb out quite spectacularly (this is a plugin and normally a crash will be caught by the host - but this one takes out the host program as well! As I said quite spectacular)

```
void PtBranchAndBoundIterationOriginRunner::runOrigin(int origin, int time) const // NOTE: const method
{
    BOOST_FOREACH(int accessMode, m_props->GetAccessModes())
    {
        // get a const reference to appropriate vector from member variable
        // map<int, vector<double>> m_rowTotalsByAccessMode;
        const vector<double>& rowTotalsForAccessMode = m_rowTotalsByAccessMode.find(accessMode)->second;

        if (origin != 129) continue; // Additional debug constrain: I know that the vector only has one non-zero element at index 129

        m_job->Write("size: " + ToString(rowTotalsForAccessMode.size()));
        try {
            // check for early return... i.e. nothing to do for this origin 
            if (!rowTotalsForAccessMode[origin])    continue; // <- this works
            if (!rowTotalsForAccessMode.at(origin)) continue; // <- this crashes
        } catch (...) {
            m_job->Write("Caught an exception"); // but its not an exception
        }

        // do some other stuff
    }
}
```

I hate not putting in well defined questions but at the moment my best phrasing is : "WTF?"

I'm compiling this with Intel C++ 11.0.074 [IA-32] using Microsoft (R) Visual Studio Version 9.0.21022.8 and my implementation of vector has

```
const_reference operator[](size_type _Pos) const
{   // subscript nonmutable sequence

#if _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING
    if (size() <= _Pos)
    {
        _DEBUG_ERROR("vector subscript out of range");
        _SCL_SECURE_OUT_OF_RANGE;
    }
#endif /* _HAS_ITERATOR_DEBUGGING */
    _SCL_SECURE_VALIDATE_RANGE(_Pos < size());

    return (*(_Myfirst + _Pos));
}
```

(Iterator debugging is off - I'm pretty sure) and

```
const_reference at(size_type _Pos) const
{   // subscript nonmutable sequence with checking
    if (size() <= _Pos)
        _Xran();
    return (*(begin() + _Pos));
}
```

So the only difference I can see is that at calls begin instead of simply using _Myfirst - but how could that possibly be causing such a huge difference in behaviour?

**UPDATE**:

The index is within range - the size is printed out as 377 and the index is constrained to 129.

The member variable has an entry corresponding to accessMode

The entire thing has been wrapped in the following to clarify @nikko suggestion:

```
map<int, vector<double>>::const_iterator it = m_rowTotalsByAccessMode.find(accessMode);
if (it != m_rowTotalsByAccessMode.end())
{
    ...
```

**UPDATE** I've upgraded my compiler to the latest version 11.1.065 and this is no longer happening. Looks like it was weirdness somewhere.

Comment: for the update: "index is constrained to 129" , you are not checking with `>=` instead you are doing `!=` . Is that intended?

Comment: If you look at the comment in the code, it looks like it's intended.

Comment: I saw the comment, but the statement in the update got me bit confused.

Comment: What happen if you do it in a simple test program? Maybe you have some memory corruption, or a problem with the plugin compilation. Do you work on objects that are shared between the plugin and the main program?

Comment: @nikko, I haven't tried to isolate this in a test program yet. I think memory corruption is the likeliest answer but from where I have no idea - normally if it is memory you can fix the symptom (at versus []) and the problem will then pop up somewhere else - but in this case I can't get it to crash except with this line - I even turned the multithreading on and ran with 8 threads - rock solid :(

Comment: About the update, the only thing worse than having a crash that you can't find the cause of, is having it disappear without knowing what fixed it ;)

Comment: @Andreas - I know!!!! It's eating me up inside, but I don't think there is anything I can do about it. I can't even file a bug report against the 11.0.074 compiler because all my efforts to isolate the problem were for naught :( Thanks to everyone for their help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hate answering my own questions but this seems to be a situation where it is required. As it says in the update, I downloaded and installed the latest intel c++ compiler and recompiled from scratch which seems to have fixed the problem. I've also rebuilt the entire project from scratch using the 11.0.074 compiler to rule out a corruption of one of the binaries; even a clean build results in the crash!

I'm going to follow this up on the Intel forums, thanks to everyone who put in some time and effort to this problem.

Answer (score 3):

I did not see where you checked that rowTotalsForAccessMode was valid. Maybe your "m_rowTotalsByAccessMode.find(accessMode)" does not work.

You should check the result of your .find() against iterator end() to see if it's valid

Comment: +1 I think the OP will eventually find out that the `[]`-version not crashing is a fluke.

Comment: Good point nikko, but for the purposes of the question, it has been found... I populate it explicitly

Comment: +1 to Nikko, these two scratched my eye as well. So actually the problem exists in both scenarios, it's just that the one with '[]' silently does ABW and the one with 'at()' throws. The uncaugt exception is causing program to "abort" on *nix, not sure how it maps to MS though.

Comment: @bobah: But there is `catch(...)` which should catch the exception unless this code is getting executed in a stack unwinding process.

Comment: @bobah: except that it's not an exception at the at call point... it's a god-awful coredump.... but you are right - if .find() returns end() then I attempt to deference the end pointer that would put things into a pretty bad state.

Comment: @Naveen - yes, right, missed it, so it's not out of range exception.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you single step the program in a debugger (into `at`) and see what is causing the crash? There are two options:

1. `rowTotalsForAccessMode` is invalid
2. `origin` is out of range

Comment: sorry... only occurs in release mode.

Comment: You should be able to single step in release as well, no?

Comment: Visual Studio does some weird jumping around in Release mode.. I have no examples, but if memory serves me right (hehe), I  usually saw it when I had memory corruption (which I guess debug mode compensates for?)

Comment: No, that's not it. The debugger does jump around a bit in release mode but it's because the optimizations may have moved/removed/inlined/unrolled code etc. This doesn't stop you from single stepping into functions though and finding the point of the crash.

Comment: Most likely all the standard library code is inlined though. I'm not sure how well the debugger would handle that

Comment: It depends, the standard library code doesn't get any special treatment, it will be inlined to the same extent as all other code. If you have a complicated function in the standard library it most certainly won't be inlined.